# how do I draw a rectangle around a text in html canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I know I read a couple of stuff about ascent and font height in canvas but I simply don't get it.

First of all why is the text drawn from right to top instead of the form right to bottom like with rectangles. I can't find that anywhere in the doc. And then what do I do if I want to draw a rectangle around a letter, especially 'y' or 'p' the ones that go below the baseline.

I have a [canvas with text](http://jsfiddle.net/5pbko680/7/),

```
 ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.fillText('Hello yyyqqqppp', 50, 50);
  ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.closePath();
```

what do I do to get the rectangle drawn around it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, a few misconceptions :

- [`ctx.closePath()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/closePath) method does close a Path2D that is still open : i.e `ctx.moveTo(10,10); ctx.lineTo(50, 50); ctx.lineTo(30, 50);` will leave an unclosed path. Calling closePath() will create the last `ctx.lineTo(10,10)` for you.
  `ctx.rect()` is therefore always a closed path, no need to call this method.
  `ctx.fill()` will close the path for you.
  `ctx.fillText()` doesn't produce a path and already includes the `fill()` method, no need to call it again.

Now, why is the baseline specified instead of the top of the text, it is because by default the [`ctx.textBaseline`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/textBaseline) property is set to `"bottom"`. You can set it to `"top"`if you need.

To get the position and the size of a letter in your text, you can use the [`ctx.measureText()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/measureText) method.

So for your example you can end with :

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector( "canvas" );
const ctx = canvas.getContext( "2d" );

ctx.font = "50px Arial";
// the text position
const x = 50, y = 50;
// the text to draw
const str = "Hello yyyqqqppp";
// the characters to find
const chars_to_find = [ "o", "y", "p" ];

ctx.strokeStyle = "red";

// get the index of every characters we're interested in
const chars_indice = [];
for ( let i = 0; i < str.length; i++ ) {
  if ( chars_to_find.includes( str[ i ] ) ) {
    chars_indice.push( i );
  }
}
//iterate through the characters list
for ( let i = 0; i < chars_indice.length; i++ ) {
  const previous_text = str.substring( 0, chars_indice[ i ] );
  const previous_text_width = ctx.measureText( previous_text ).width;
  const char = str.substring( chars_indice[ i ], chars_indice[ i ] + 1 );
  const char_bbox = getTextBBox( ctx, char );

  const left = previous_text_width + char_bbox.left;
  const { top, width, height } = char_bbox;
  const half_line = ctx.lineWidth / 2;
  // draw the rect
  ctx.strokeRect( left + x - half_line, top + y - half_line, width + ctx.lineWidth, height + ctx.lineWidth);
}
// draw our text
ctx.fillText( str, x, y );

function getTextBBox( ctx, text ) {
  const metrics = ctx.measureText( text );
  const left = metrics.actualBoundingBoxLeft * -1;
  const top = metrics.actualBoundingBoxAscent * -1;
  const right = metrics.actualBoundingBoxRight;
  const bottom = metrics.actualBoundingBoxDescent;
  // actualBoundinBox... excludes white spaces
  const width = text.trim() === text ? right - left : metrics.width;
  const height = bottom - top;
  return { left, top, right, bottom, width, height };
}
```

```html
<canvas width="500"></canvas>
```

Comment: Omg thank you so much! I think I'm slowly understanding how it works, thank you so much!

Answer (score 5):

**Here are some keys to drawing a rectangle around text**

If you want the text to be aligned from the top-left then you can set these context alignment properties:

```
context.textAlign='left';  // this is the default to align horizontally to the left
context.textBaseline='top';  // text will be aligned vertically to the top
```

You can measure the horizontal width of text using this context method:

```
// set the font size and font face before measuring
context.font='14px verdana';
var textWidth=context.measureText('Hello').width;
```

There is no native canvas way to measure text height, but for most fonts and non-extreme font sizes I've worked with you can get a good approximation of the height like this:

```
var lineHeight=fontsizeInPixels * 1.286;
```

**Example code and a Demo:**

```js
// get references to canvas and context
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var fontsize = 14;
var fontface = 'verdana';
var lineHeight = fontsize * 1.286;
var text = 'Draw a rectangle around me.';

ctx.font = fontsize + 'px ' + fontface;
var textWidth = ctx.measureText(text).width;

ctx.textAlign = 'left';
ctx.textBaseline = 'top';

ctx.fillText(text, 20, 50);
ctx.strokeRect(20, 50, textWidth, lineHeight);
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<canvas id=canvas width=300 height=300></canvas>
```

Comment: Han, I started to wrote something along this... I'll post it because I gone through the split each chars steps but +1 because I use your approximation you gave me in an other answer.

Comment: @Kaiido. I notice now the questioner wants to put rects around individual letters -- I missed that. I'm upvoting your answer since it rectangles individual letters. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks, but both answers are basically the same so I feel kinda weird about it.

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you, the 5th time you helped me a lot! Just out of curiosityt to see if I understood the concept. So with `lineHeight` I get the `lineHeight` of the text. And `height = ascent + descent`, so `ascent` is the font in pixel so `14` right? `descent` would be `lineHeight - 14`

Comment: yeah, I think that should be it, thank you so much! http://jsfiddle.net/5pbko680/8/

Comment: how did you find this number `1.286` ?

Comment: @PaulBernhardWagner. No magical conjuring in 1.286. :-) It's just the browser's standard lineHeight ratio for 14px fonts and it still yields a nice spacing for the usual font sizes above and below 14px.

Comment: In my experience, yes. I routinely use font sizes from 10 to 18.

Answer (score 3):

In order to draw a border around your text, your context needs to know what font is currently set. After you establish that, you can call `ctx.measureText(text)`. This will compute the width of the text, and the height measurements can be determined with the bounding ascent and descent values.

The function `drawBorderedText` function below is highly configurable. I added a gutter to showcase the offsets. You should provide an `x` and `y` value; but if you take advantage of the `alignment` and `justification` config option, you can just set them to `(0, 0)` and the function will take care of positioning.

**Note:** Multi-line text is not accounted for at this time.

```js
const ctx = document.querySelector('#target').getContext('2d');

const SCREEN_WIDTH = ctx.canvas.width = 480;
const SCREEN_HEIGHT = ctx.canvas.height = 160;

const textOptions = {
  borderColor: '#F00',
  borderSize: 1,
  fontColor: '#0F0',
  fontFamily: 'Consolas',
  fontSize: 14,
  lineDash: [8, 4],
  padding: 6,
};

const gutterSize = 12;

const main = () => {
  ctx.fillStyle = '#000';
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT);

  drawBorderedText(ctx, 'Top-Left', 0, 0, {
    ...textOptions,
    alignment: 'top',
    justification: 'left',
    offsetX: gutterSize,
    offsetY: gutterSize
  });

  drawBorderedText(ctx, 'Top-Center', 0, 0, {
    ...textOptions,
    alignment: 'top',
    justification: 'center',
    offsetX: 0,
    offsetY: gutterSize
  });

  drawBorderedText(ctx, 'Top-Right', 0, 0, {
    ...textOptions,
    alignment: 'top',
    justification: 'right',
    offsetX: -gutterSize,
    offsetY: gutterSize
  });

  drawBorderedText(ctx, 'Middle-Left', 0, 0, {
    ...textOptions,
    alignment: 'middle',
    justification: 'left',
    offsetX: gutterSize,
    offsetY: 0
  });

  drawBorderedText(ctx, 'Middle-Center', 0, 0, {
    ...textOptions,
    alignment: 'middle',
    justification: 'center',
    offsetX: 0,
    offsetY: 0
  });

  drawBorderedText(ctx, 'Middle-Right', 0, 0, {
    ...textOptions,
    alignment: 'middle',
    justification: 'right',
    offsetX: -gutterSize,
    offsetY: 0
  });

  drawBorderedText(ctx, 'Bottom-Left', 0, 0, {
    ...textOptions,
    alignment: 'bottom',
    justification: 'left',
    offsetX: gutterSize,
    offsetY: -gutterSize
  });

  drawBorderedText(ctx, 'Bottom-Center', 0, 0, {
    ...textOptions,
    alignment: 'bottom',
    justification: 'center',
    offsetX: 0,
    offsetY: -gutterSize
  });

  drawBorderedText(ctx, 'Bottom-Right', 0, 0, {
    ...textOptions,
    alignment: 'bottom',
    justification: 'right',
    offsetX: -gutterSize,
    offsetY: -gutterSize
  });
};

const drawBorderedText = (ctx, text, x, y, options = {}) => {
  const {
    alignment,
    borderColor,
    borderSize,
    fontColor,
    fontFamily,
    fontSize,
    justification,
    lineDash,
    padding,
    offsetX,
    offsetY
  } = { ...borderdTextDefaultOptions, ...options };

  ctx.save();
  ctx.font = `${fontSize}px ${fontFamily}`;

  const borderOffset = Math.floor(borderSize / 2);
  const { actualHeight, fontHeight, fontWidth  } = calcFontMetrics(ctx, text);
  const x2 = x + fontWidth + (borderSize * 2) + (padding * 2);
  const y2 = y + actualHeight + (borderSize * 2) + (padding * 2);
  const justifyX = computeJustification(justification, ctx.canvas.width, x2);
  const alignY = computeAlignment(alignment, ctx.canvas.height, y2);
  const x1 = x + offsetX + justifyX;
  const y1 = y + offsetY + alignY;

  ctx.textAlign = 'left';
  ctx.textBaseline = 'top';
  // Border
  ctx.setLineDash(lineDash);
  ctx.lineWidth = borderSize;
  ctx.strokeStyle = borderColor;
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.rect(
    x1 + borderOffset + 0.5,
    y1 + borderOffset + 0.5,
    fontWidth + borderSize + (padding * 2),
    actualHeight + borderSize + (padding * 2),
  );
  ctx.stroke();
  // Text
  ctx.fillStyle = fontColor;
  ctx.fillText(text, x1 + borderSize + padding, y1 + borderSize + padding);

  ctx.restore();
};

const borderdTextDefaultOptions = {
  alignment: 'top',
  borderColor: '#000',
  borderSize: 1,
  fontColor: '#000',
  fontFamily: 'Arial',
  fontSize: 12,
  justification: 'left',
  lineDash: [],
  padding: 0,
  offsetX: 0,
  offsetY: 0
};

const calcFontMetrics = (ctx, text) => {
  const {
    actualBoundingBoxAscent: abba,
    actualBoundingBoxDescent: abbd,
    fontBoundingBoxAscent: fbba,
    fontBoundingBoxDescent: fbbd,
    width
  } = ctx.measureText(text);
  return {
    actualHeight: abba + abbd,
    fontHeight: fbba + fbbd,
    fontWidth: width
  };
};

const computeAlignment = (alignment, parent, child) => {
  switch (alignment) {
    case 'top': return 0;
    case 'middle': return Math.floor((parent / 2) - (child / 2));
    case 'bottom': return parent - child;
    default: return NaN;
  }
};

const computeJustification = (justification, parent, child) => {
  switch (justification) {
    case 'left': return 0;
    case 'center': return Math.floor((parent / 2) - (child / 2));
    case 'right': return parent - child;
    default: return NaN;
  }
};

main();
```

```css
html, body { width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0; background: #111; }
body { display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center; }
```

```html
<canvas id="target"></canvas>
```